# SQL count number of common matches using several WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having columns like: `membership_id | user_id | group_id`

[image]

I'm looking for a SQL query to get the number of common groups between 2 different users. I could do that in several queries and using some PHP but I'd like to know if there is a way to use only SQL for that.

Like with the user ids 1 and 3, there are 3 common groups (1, 5 and 6) so the result returned would be 3.

I've made several tests but so far no result...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "multiple WHERE clauses" or even a self JOIN:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM theTable AS t
WHERE t.user_id IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2;
```

more generically

```
SELECT group_id
FROM theTable AS t
WHERE t.user_id IN ([user id list])
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = [# of user ids in list];
```

---

Edit: Oh, you wanted the number of groups....

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
  SELECT group_id
  FROM theTable AS t
  WHERE t.user_id IN (1, 3)
  GROUP BY group_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2
);
```

Comment: Thank you that works! :) Just, if you have 20 sec, what is the purpose of this part: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2 ? Thank you again

Comment: Without the HAVING, you would get every group_id associated with *either* user. The `=2` insures the group is associated with both users, and the `distinct` is just in case the user-group associations are not unique (i.e. so you wouldn't get group 4 if user 1 was associated with it twice and 3 wasn't associated with it at all).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with join.

Try this:

```
select t1.user_id, t2.user_id, group_concat(distinct t1.group_id)
from your_table t1
join your_table t2
on t1.user_id < t2.user_id
and t1.group_id = t2.group_id
group by t1.user_id, t2.user_id;
```

If you don't want a concatenated output:

```
select distinct t1.user_id, t2.user_id, t1.group_id
from your_table t1
join your_table t2
on t1.user_id < t2.user_id
and t1.group_id = t2.group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to join two instances of the same table (for each of them you select only the records relative to one of the users) using group_id as join attribute, and count the result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.group_id=t2.group_id
WHERE t1.user_id=1 AND t2.user_id=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   TABLE_NAME USER_ONE_INFO
       TABLE_NAME USER_TWO_INFO
WHERE  USER_ONE_INFO.ID = USER_ONE_ID
AND    USER_TWO_INFO.ID = USER_TWO_ID
AND    USER_ONE_INFO.GROUP_ID = USER_TWO_INFO.GROUP_ID;
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.